# GLUT function key stop refreshing

Tags: opengl, freeglut

I've used FreeGLUT 3.0.0 (built from source using MSVC 2013) under Windows 7 to create an OpenGL context for quite a while, but today I encountered some strange behavior: **When I press the `F10` key, the window stops to refresh**. Following is the minimal code that will achieve this strange behavior under MSVC 2013, Windows 7:

```
#define FREEGLUT_STATIC
#include <gl/glut.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void init()
{
    glClearColor(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}

void display()
{
    cout << "a" << endl;
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glutSwapBuffers();
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void reshapeFunc(int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, 640, 480);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutCreateWindow("What?");

    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshapeFunc);

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

In this example, when I press `F10`, the command line stops to print the character 'a', and continues when I press `F10` again.

The strange thing is that I didn't do anything special to `F10` (I encountered this problem since the point I didn't write anything like `GLUT_KEY_F10`). All other function key don't have this problem. I don't why this is specific to the `F10` key.

Does anyone have any suggestion about how to deal with this problem?

Comment: Edit in a [mcve] & more information about your environment (OS, FreeGLUT version, is FreeGLUT built from source or are you using binaries, etc.).

Comment: @genpfault Thx. I've edited the question with a minimal runnable code where the problem still shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested [here](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/470834-help-with-wm_keydown-sc_keymenu--f10-key-press/?view=findpost&p=4093342):

> F10 is the shortcut key to enter a windows' menu. It should be enough to not pass a valid HMENU handle. I haven't tested this though. You probably want to avoid using F10 if it doesn't work though.
>
> **If you insist, you can get F10 by catching WM_SYSKEYDOWN and NOT passing the message on to DefWindowProc.**

Adding a flag to skip the `DefWindowProc()` call on `SC_KEYMENU` events to [FreeGLUT's `WM_SYSCOMMAND` handler](https://github.com/dcnieho/FreeGLUT/blob/git_master/freeglut/freeglut/src/mswin/fg_main_mswin.c#L1410) seems to "fix" the problem:

```
...

    case WM_SYSCOMMAND :  /* 0x0112 */
        {
            /* HACKITTY HACK HACK HACK */
            int skipDefWindowProc = 0;
            {
                /*
                * We have received a system command message.  Try to act on it.
                * The commands are passed in through the "wParam" parameter:
                * The least significant digit seems to be which edge of the window
                * is being used for a resize event:
                *     4  3  5
                *     1     2
                *     7  6  8
                * Congratulations and thanks to Richard Rauch for figuring this out..
                */
                switch ( wParam & 0xfff0 )
                {
                case SC_SIZE       :
                    break ;

                case SC_MOVE       :
                    break ;

                case SC_MINIMIZE   :
                    /* User has clicked on the "-" to minimize the window */
                    /* Turning off the visibility is handled in WM_SIZE handler */

                    break ;

                case SC_MAXIMIZE   :
                    break ;

                case SC_NEXTWINDOW :
                    break ;

                case SC_PREVWINDOW :
                    break ;

                case SC_CLOSE      :
                    /* Followed very closely by a WM_CLOSE message */
                    break ;

                case SC_VSCROLL    :
                    break ;

                case SC_HSCROLL    :
                    break ;

                case SC_MOUSEMENU  :
                    break ;

                case SC_KEYMENU    :
                    skipDefWindowProc = 1;
                    break ;

                case SC_ARRANGE    :
                    break ;

                case SC_RESTORE    :
                    break ;

                case SC_TASKLIST   :
                    break ;

                case SC_SCREENSAVE :
                    break ;

                case SC_HOTKEY     :
                    break ;

#if(WINVER >= 0x0400)
                case SC_DEFAULT    :
                    break ;

                case SC_MONITORPOWER    :
                    break ;

                case SC_CONTEXTHELP    :
                    break ;
#endif /* WINVER >= 0x0400 */

                default:
#if _DEBUG
                    fgWarning( "Unknown wParam type 0x%x", wParam );
#endif
                    break;
                }
            }
#endif /* !defined(_WIN32_WCE) */

            /* We need to pass the message on to the operating system as well */
            if( skipDefWindowProc == 0 )
            {
                lRet = DefWindowProc( hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam );
            }
            break;
        }

...
```

Comment: Thanks genpfault, I've tried this and it indeed worked :)